# AI Snake BFS Issue

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, robotics, breadth-first-search

I am working on solving snake boxing itself problem. I believe that If I use Breadth-First Search (BFS) to make a move, it can reduce the risk of being boxed greatly. My question is how many possible empty spaces (connected) I should look for to make sure that this move will not result in boxing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance you have to look to see if you are boxed in is always going to depend on the size/position of the snake. The only way to be 100% sure is to search all moves in advance, and avoid moves that lead the snake to be boxed in. That said, you might have better luck with a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) over breadth-first, because it can rapidly find a dead end (if it exists). Then avoid those moves. In your second example, depth-first would quickly find that moving "up" is a dead end.

Comment: DPS goes until it reaches a dead end, or (likely) a depth limit. So it would explore up until it hit the dead end. Step 1: move head up, Step 2: move head up (only 1 move available), Step 3: move head up, Step 4: move head up, Step 5: Dead end because there are no legal moves.

Comment: The algorithm has to increment the game too. So each time it "moves up," the tail of the snake moves too. If the left side was 5 in length, then it would know that it doesn't lead to a dead end.

Comment: Yes, but only if the dead end is unavoidable. This example is similar to your second, but the dead end is still avoidable even after moving up 1 space. Well it won't let me paste it. But if you move the bottom 5 parts of the snake over left one, then you have the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of moves deep you need to search the game tree is related to the square area the snake can contain when it encircles itself.  For example, a length 12 snake:

```
----
|00|
|00|
91--
```

If the snake goes up (north), it can still live but only if it then goes east.  if it goes north again, then it dies.

The maximum area a snake can contain is: (length/4 - 1)^2.  When this is fractional, you probably want to round up.